# How to preserve user's CustomUI Ribbon in Excel using VBA or XML

Tags: excel, xml, vba, ribbon

I have an Excel Add-In with a number of small subs, that upon initializing creates a Custom tab on the Ribbon to control said subs. I use VBA string with XML code to modify Ribbon (see the code below).

The Add-In is meant to be shared with a number of users, most of whom already have some customization in place. The problem is, that Add-In deletes any custom settings user might have on his Excel Ribbon, be it tabs, buttons or a shortcut.

I've played with this problem for a few days and was unable to find a solution. I need it to add a custom tab to an already existing ribbon, rather then overwrite it.

Part of the sub that creates a Custom Tab for an Add-In controls is below

```
Sub CreateRibbon()

'create a custom ribbon menu'

Dim hFile As Long
Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String

    hFile = FreeFile
    
    path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"
    fileName = "Excel.officeUI"
    
    ribbonXML = "<mso:customUI      xmlns:mso='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  <mso:ribbon startFromScratch='false'>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:qat/>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
                'tab'
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      <mso:tab id='MicroHelpers' label='Helpers' insertBeforeQ='mso:TabFormat'>" & vbNewLine
                'group'
                
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <mso:group id='MassFormulas' label='Mass Formula' autoScale='true'>" & vbNewLine
            
            ribbonXML = ribbonXML + AddButtonXML("TextToNum", "WordCount", "Text To Num")
            
        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </mso:group>" & vbNewLine

                .....

        ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </mso:group>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      </mso:tab>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    </mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  </mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "</mso:customUI>"
    
    ribbonXML = Replace(ribbonXML, """", "")
    
    Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
    Print #hFile, ribbonXML
    Close hFile

end sub
```

I'll be grateful for some guidance

Comment: Why don't you just use the CustomUI part of your add-in?

Comment: Lots of discussion here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba   The thing seems to be that if you add custom UI at run-time you need to remove it later, but not just by clearing the users Custom UI completely, but by returning it to its original state.  That's not a simple thing to do (what if another add-in modified it after yours loaded?) so using the customIUEditor tool is the "best" approach.

Comment: @Rory, what do you mean?

Comment: @TimWilliams, using an Editor is, indeed, the simplest way, but unfortunately, I can't use any additional software due to my company's policy. Plus, I didn't quite get the delete part of your message. I don't need to clear Ribbon at WorkBook close, the tab should be present at all times. It's like a one-time activation thing, meant to be installed once and used daily.

Comment: I assumed you were deleting the custom xml when you closed your add-in.  FYI you do not need the CustomUI editor - it can all be done other ways eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772723/create-excel-2007-ribbon-without-custom-ui-editor

Comment: Yes, @TimWilliams, thank you. I know how to create and import a CustomUI, it works great. The problem is that I also need to combine my CustomUI with whatever CustomUI the end user has. I was thinking about exportingUI, reading it, incorporating my xml code and importing it back.

Comment: If your CustomUI is embedded in your add-in (not constructed and added on load) all of that happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For all of you, who suffered with this, the same way I did. I've figured it out.

The problem was, that when the end user tried to install an add-in, it overwrote his ribbon customization, deleting everything and showing only my code. The solution turned out to be very simple:

Before creating a new tab, I've extracted the XML code FROM Excel.officeUI file, embedding my code into already existing one

```
hFile = FreeFile
user = Environ("Username")
path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"

Open path & fileName For Input Access Read As hFile
bubble_local = Input(LOF(hFile), hFile)
Close hFile

'main macro part'

Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
Print #hFile, ribbonXML
Close hFile
```

This way user's customization are preserved. I don't know why it took me so long, but to me it wasn't obvious. I hope it will save some of you the struggle

BTW, due to the use of Excel.officeUI, I've found that the only way to refresh the ribbon is to reload Excel